# Is it suitable to use "formation" for mainly lava units as a lithostratigraphic unit?

Tags: stratigraphy, volcanics, lava, stratovolcanoe, formation

I want to give lithostragraphic name for a stratovolcanoe rocks. Is it suitable to use "FORMATION" for these rocks, where it composed  of mainly lava, dome lavas, autobreccia, and minor pyroclastic density current units with feeder dykes.